# Tensorflow graph size

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering if there is an easy way to check the size/memory needed of a tensorflow graph before running a tensorflow session.

I am looking for something where I can keep changing my system parameters that define the graph and can see how big (in memory) the graph becomes accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar where I wanted to see the number of parameters in my model.

```
vars = 0
for v in tf.all_variables():
    vars += np.prod(v.get_shape().as_list())
print(vars)
```

Now vars contains the sum of the product of the dimensions of all the variables in your graph.  If each variable is of type tf.float32 you can multiply vars by 4 to get the number of bytes consumed by all of the variables.  This however is just a lower bound and there will be some additional overhead.  Also I think computing the gradients requires a lot of memory since it needs to store the activations at each point in the model for the backwards pass.

Comment: tf.all_variables() now is tf.global_variables()

Answer (score 1):

Given tensor `t`:

```
var_sizes = [np.product(list(map(int, v.get_shape())))*v.dtype.size
             for key in t.graph.get_all_collection_keys() for v in f.graph.get_collection_ref(key)]
print(sum(var_sizes)/(1024**2), 'MB')
```

Comment: f.graph = t.graph